# swift: call willDisplay

Tags: ios, swift

I have `collectionView`. And I have code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "purchase") {

        myCell.cover.image = nil

    }
}
```

Also I have `secondViewController`. I use this code to go `secondViewController`:

```
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let imageRevealVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InfoViewController") as! InfoViewController
imageRevealVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
self.present(imageRevealVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

If I buy product I need that after returning from `secondViewController` code calls `willDisplaycell` to remove images. Is it possible?

Comment: you have to reload the cell

Comment: @Spidvmp `collectionView.reloadData()` ?

Comment: u can reload only that cell, collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexpath])

Comment: @Spidvmp Where I should reload?

Comment: Use delegate don't call it in viewwillAppear it will call even if you don't select anything

Answer (score 0):

As you get the idea from the comments too, that you should reload the collectionView to make any changes to the UI of the collectionView's cell once it is loaded and there will be any data source changes. Like you want to make the edit to state of purchased products or wants to deleted the purchased items from the list.

**Now, where should you do the updates?**

Every time when you pop the viewController, it will takes you to previous viewController. And viewWillAppear Method will be invoked.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated)    
  self.collectionView.reloadData() 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have send your view controller to secondViewController

create a property in secondViewController

```
var parentVC: YOURVIEWCONTROLLER?
```

when create secondViewController, send the parent

```
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
imageRevealVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InfoViewController") as! InfoViewController
imageRevealVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext

imageRevealVC.parentVC = self

self.present(imageRevealVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

In secondViewcontroller do what you have to do and change the data model. When finish, in okButton, for example, call to parentVC to reload that index path

```
self.parentVC?.reloadItem()
```

in your parentViewController create a fun to reload the index path selected. you have to save it before going to seconfViewController

```
func reloadItem() {
   self.collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([savevindexpath]) 
}
```